# Angularjs loop async void calls

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

i have this piece of code here

```
A preloaded list through a rest call...

$scope.loadedList = [{a:1,flag:false},{a:2,flag:false},{a:3,flag:false}];

angular.forEach($scope.loadedList, function( value , key ) {
    if (value.a < 3){
      ...rest call that changes the flag to true at database, with void return}

    return $scope.loadedList.length; --> This is 3 and it's ok
}).then(_loadedListLength){
    ...a rest call to get the list again, with falg = false
```

Here is the problem. **_loadedListLength = 3** , and this is ok cause i didn't change the elements inside the list.

However, the second call (which retrieves only elements with flag = false) returns exactly the list it was at the beginning.

Appearently, those calls inside the loop are not completed before i retrieve again the list.

**What i've tried**

I found that i should push each promises in the loop inside an array, let's call it **promises** and do something like:

```
$q.all(promises).then(doSomethingAfterAllRequests);
```

The problem is that those calls inside the loop are void.

If i had to sum up the problem in one question:

*How do i wait the completion of a series of asynchronous void calls inside a loop before performing another call to the server?*

Thanks

Comment: Although your requests "doesn't" return a value, it will return `200` if OK. So if you use the `$q.all(..)` the success callback will only occur when all the promises finished with success status. What went wrong when you tried this approach? It's not clear to me. Can you show the code that you populate the `promises` array?

Comment: Thanks Luiz, i just got to the point you were suggesting me. I needed actually the number of completed calls after they were finished and it does not matter if they return void, i still have a void response object in my array to use as count.

Thanks for the help